# uncheck radio button with laravel and jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to get a radio button with bootstrap (button) style with the rules:

- Each Section can have only one button checked (i thought it may be easy with the radio button)
- Each Section have 3 option, data coming from database.

**Current html stucture**:

```
<div class="col" id="matches">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="{{$match->api_id}}" id="{{$match->api_id}}/{{$match->home_team}}" data-team="{{$match->home_team}}" data-apiid="{{$match->api_id}}" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" style="width: 100%;" for="{{$match->api_id}}/{{$match->home_team}}"><small>{{$match->home_team}}</small><br>{{$match->odds_h2h_home}} x</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="{{$match->api_id}}" id="{{$match->api_id}}/x" data-team="x" data-apiid="{{$match->api_id}}" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" style="width: 100%;" for="{{$match->api_id}}/x"><small>Draw</small><br>{{$match->odds_h2h_x}} x</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="{{$match->api_id}}" id="{{$match->api_id}}/{{$match->away_team}}" data-team="{{$match->away_team}}" data-apiid="{{$match->api_id}}" autocomplete="off">
            <label class="btn btn-outline-success" style="width: 100%;" for="{{$match->api_id}}/{{$match->away_team}}"><small>{{$match->away_team}}</small><br>{{$match->odds_h2h_away}} x</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$(this).prop("checked", false );` or with attr, I can't check if the radio button was already checked if yes then remove the checked first.

Can someone help me to get this work?

**Current JQuery**:

```
$( "input[type=radio]" ).on( "click", function() => {
    $.each($('input[type="radio"]:checked'), function() {
        not sure what need to do here?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want radio buttons to function like checkboxes, I guess you could do the following:

```js
$( "input[type=radio]" ).on( "click", event => event.target.checked = !event.target.checked);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. With this code work all radio button as checkboxes. Is it possible to keep the rule of radio button. I need if click it after checked it must uncheck it but the selection rules must be the same (Same html name can have one select. 2 html names will have 2 selection then)